# CC-Mode 5.32.1 with Latest Emacs

Tags: emacs, trunk, cc-mode

I'm trying cc-mode 5.32.1 with Emacs trunk. When I compile I get these errors

```
cc-mode.el:596:29:Error: Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-obsolete

Compiling file /home/per/pnw/emacs/cc-mode-5.32.1/cc-styles.el at Sun Oct  2 12:28:53 2011
cc-styles.el:654:29:Error: Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-obsolete
```

Load completes without erros but I when I try to edit in my new version of c-mode I get these errors:

```
Error during redisplay: (void-function buffer-syntactic-context) [2 times]
byte-code: End of buffer [3 times]
ad-Orig-c-indent-line: Wrong type argument: listp, cc-bytecomp-ignore-var:c-syntactic-contextError during redisplay: (void-function buffer-syntactic-context) [2 times]
c-in-literal: Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-syntactic-context
ad-Orig-c-indent-line: Wrong type argument: listp, cc-bytecomp-ignore-var:c-syntactic-contextError during redisplay: (void-function buffer-syntactic-context)
c-in-literal: Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-syntactic-context
ad-Orig-c-indent-line: Wrong type argument: listp, cc-bytecomp-ignore-var:c-syntactic-contextError during redisplay: (void-function buffer-syntactic-context)
c-in-literal: Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-syntactic-context [2 times]
```

Is there an easy way out of this problem or should I wait for the emacs developers to fix this. I know quit a lot about Emacs-Lisp but this problem beats me.

Maybe a hint: When I lookup `buffer-syntactic-context` i get

```
buffer-syntactic-context is an alias for `cc-bytecomp-ignore-fun:buffer-syntactic-context',
which is not defined.  Please make a bug report.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in CC-Mode version 5.32.2 meaning it's now compatible with Emacs trunk. Thanks Alan.